# How can I use the yup validation for the Field as a select in vueJS

Tags: vue.js, validation, vue-component, yup, vee-validate

How can I use the yup validation for the field as a select.

```
    <Form>
        <Field name="gender" as="select" v-model="gender">
        <option value="" >Choose one</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
        <option value="other">other</option>
        <ErrorMessage name="gender" class="error-feedback"></ErrorMessage>
    </Field>
    </Form>
```

When I tried to add a lib like "required" in the object schema I get the following error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: yup__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.required is not a function
```

My Yup Rules and initial Data:

```
data(){
   const schema = yup.object().shape({
        titel:yup
             .string()
             .required(this.getErrorMsg("Titel required"))
             .max(40,"must be a maximum of 40 characters long!"),
        //gender:yup.required(this.getErrorMsg("please select one")),
         });
       return{
            schema,
            titel:"",
            gender:"",
         }
```

How can I achieve it using yup.Please help me out this problem.

Thanks in advance.